# A Conditional Sentence in Direct and Indirect Speech

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In the film "Spartacus" (1960) Marcus Publius Glabrus, having just lost six cohorts of the garrison of Rome, in an ill-starred attempt to crush the slave-uprising in its incipient stages, is summoned to the Senate for a debriefing. Senator Gracchus rises to his feet:

> "If we had punished every commander, who made a fool of himself, we'd have no-one left above the rank of centurion."

Translating this into both direct & indirect speech: it's a conditional sentence; impossible conditions (it did not happen: we did not punish every commander). In advanced texts e.g. Allen & Greenough "impossible conditions" is called "contrary-to-fact" i.e. "counterfactual".

FIRST CLAUSE: (The protasis: a statement of the condition.)

A counterfactual condition, in the past tense, requiring a pluperfect subjunctive for the verb.

SECOND CLAUSE:

A relative "qui" clause. In direct speech the verb is in the indicative.

THIRD CLAUSE: (The apodosis: the result of the condition.)

The present-tense consequence of action/ inaction, in the past, requiring the imperfect subjunctive.

TRANSLATION:

> "si puniissemus (punivissemus) omnem imperatorem, qui se ludificatus est, neminem (relinquentem) maioris ordinis centurione haberemus."

INDIRECT SPEECH:

> Gracchus told the Senators that if they had punished every commander, who had made a fool of himself, they would have no-one left above the rank of centurion."

Rules for changing a condition contrary-to-fact into indirect speech are given in (A & G) section 589; 3(b): p.383; [(https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/conditions in indirect discourse)](https://dcc)

FIRST CLAUSE:

The protasis always remains unchanged in tense.

SECOND CLAUSE:

The relative clause will require the accusative-infinitive construction for indirect speech.

THIRD CLAUSE:

(A & G): "The apodosis, if active, takes a peculiar infinitive form, made by combining the participle in -urus with fuisse."

TRANSLATION:

> Gracchus Senatoribus narravit si punissisent (punivissent) omnem imperatorem, quem se ludificatum esse, neminem (relinquentem) maioris ordinis centurione habituros fuisse.

Are the two translations correct?

Comment: In the indirect discourse version, I'm not sure that the verb in the relative clause should be infinitive. Doesn't that happen only when the relative is functioning as a so-called connecting relative (= et/sed is)? I would think subjunctive is needed in this instance.

Comment: This is an excellent question which touches upon several interesting corners of grammar; minor point (which could distract from the central questions): *punissisent* should be *punivissent*. I also doubt that *se ludificari* is a good translation for "make a fool of oneself," it sounds Latinglish to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'd think the relative clause would be subjunctive even in the direct version (relative clause of characteristic).

Comment: @TKR No, because he is not talking about a characteristic ("the sort of commander who makes a fool of himself"), but about those commanders who, however characteristic or not, did so in the actual campaign. That said, I would argue in favour of the subjunctive too, due to attraction of mode.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel; Thank you. Because "punio" has two perfect participles "punii" & "punivi", I chose "puniissent" (two "i"s; not the one "i" I used). The "ivi" form may be better therefore an edit.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Tricky was the "to make a fool of oneself" part. Oxford gives "ludificor (aliquem)"; so, "se" and not "sui" for the reflexive pronoun. Wiki gives alternative, regular verb, "ludifico".

Comment: @tony That is a rather literal translation though for an idiom which really means "to act stupidly in a disgraceful way. For lack of a better idea, I'd say: *stultitia se dedecorare*.

Comment: @TKR: Thanks. Does the relative clause of characteristic mean that the relative clause is the same in both direct & indirect speeches? Giving, "qui se ludificatus sit", selecting the perfect subjunctive (same tense as in English)? Definitely not "quem" in the indirect version?

Comment: @cnread: Thanks: I would ask yourself the same question I have put to TKR: is the relative clause, then, the same in both direct & indirect versions? Further, would imperfect subjunctive, "ludificeretur" fit for a recurring event, in the past, (according to Gracchus)?

Comment: @tony, It could be if, as Sebastian Koppehel says, the mood in the direct version is attracted into the subjunctive. Personally, I'd leave it in the indicative in the direct version, but then make it subjunctive in the indirect version (not only because verbs in subordinate clauses in indirect speech tend to be subjunctive, but also as a signal to the reader that the clause is part of the speech that is being reported rather than a comment attributable to the narrator who is reporting it).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I'd actually initially thought of calling it "attraction of mode" but then found myself wondering if there's really a difference between that and "relative clause of characteristic" in this case. That discussion is probably beyond the need of this question, though; I'm glad we agree that subjunctive is required here, in any case.

Comment: @tony The case of the relative pronoun doesn't depend on what kind of relative clause it is (characteristic or otherwise); if this were an accusative and infinitive it would be *quem*, but I agree with the other commenters that a finite clause would be used here.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Re. "attraction of mode", A & G p186; sect.306(a) Note: "urbem quam statuo vestra est" and "Naucratem, quem convenire volui, in navi non erat"; I struggled with the antecedents being in the accusative?! Wiki: "Attraction is a type of error...that incorrectly extends a feature from one word, in a sentence, to another. Here, the subjunctive, in the direct speech is an (acceptable) error--"attraction of mode"--is that correct?

Comment: @tony Per definitionem error non est quod apud Ciceronem inveniatur 

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Thanks for the answer which puts some of the above comments into focus. There is a natural tendency (Attraction?) to make an antecedent agree with the relative pronoun, because the gender & number have to agree. Why is this "mistake" legitimised with the expression, "attraction of mode"? Cicero, like Julius Caeser, did violate the rule on ablative absolutes--using a species from the AA, again, later in the same sentence. Therefore, experimenting with his own language, or mischievously looking to confound the logic of others, Cicero does not necessarily  offer perfection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of points:

- I do not think *se ludificari* is an appropriate translation for “make a fool of oneself.” As I wrote in the comments, I would prefer: *⋯ qui stultitia se dedecoravit* (who disgraced himself through foolishness).
- Relative clauses in counterfactual condicional clauses often take on the subjunctive of the governing clause, which is called *attractio modi*. The pluperfect subjunctive is *dedecoravisset*, which is quite a mouthful, though it can at least be shortened to *dedecorasset*.
- *Relinquere* does the one who leaves. The one who is left is therefore *relictus*. There is also a related, more or less synonymous word named *reliquus*. Instead of *neminem relictum/reliquum haberemus* you could also say *neminem retineremus*, but I am not sure that is necessarily better.
- I am also unsure about *maior ordo centurione*. I think a higher rank should at least be *superior* instead of *maior*. I also changed the word order with [Hor. C. 3,30](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/horace/carm3.shtml) in mind ;-)

So I would translate the direct-speech version thus:

> Si puniissemus omnem imperatorem, qui stultitia se dedecorasset, neminem ordinis centurione superioris reliquum haberemus.

For the second part:

- *Narravit* seems an unusual choice, I would have gone with a simple *dixit*.
- *Punissisent* should be *punivissent* (or *puniissent*).
- Relative clauses in an AcI context do not become AcI themselves. They retain the finite verb, but stand in the subjunctive mood, following the c.t.

So we end up with:

> Gracchus Senatoribus dixit si punivissent omnem imperatorem, qui stultitia se dedecorasset, neminem  ordinis centurione superioris reliquum habituros fuisse.

Comment: Does *puniissemus* have an extra I?

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: According to Wiki's conjugation tables; I made the mistake of a single "i" in the original posting--if it is a mistake?

Comment: @tony I see, I read too hastily. I'm not sure if the I at the end of the perfect stem is retained in all forms. Contracting to a single long I is appealing, but I'm not sure if it's done.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: Concepts e.g. "relative clause of characteristic" & "attraction of mode" are completely new to me. The latter I am still asking Seb about--it appears to be the legitimising of a mistake--do you have a thought on this one?

Comment: @tony Those concepts are well worth studying if you want to dig deeper into Latin grammar. It makes some sense to call all language evolution "legitimization of mistakes", and I see nothing deeply different in the various attraction phenomena (of mode and case) in Latin. Things don't always go as you'd expect, but language is not exactly a logic puzzle.

Comment: @tony That is a philosophical question, but personally I do not think it is a helpful framing to call attraction a legitimized mistake. To us the subjunctive, all too often, feels like a meaningless complication of grammar that we have to employ according to numerous rules when composing Latin prose. To native speakers (I suspect) it was a meaningful tool to intuitively structure their thoughts and sentences. Many of the rules we learn were dreamt up much later by philologists trying to make sense of the chaotic usage found in the sources …

Comment: … and thus you have all those [vague criteria](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/intermediate-clauses#subjunctive-integral-part) and remarks like “but other uses are occasionally found in the best authors,” etc., especially around rules concerning mood.