# What does "qua" mean in: "dedi mille argenteos, qua tu tui pudoris defensione apud omnes et tuos utaris et alienos."

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In [Gen. 20:16](https://books.google.com/books?id=-KpSAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA3-PA27&lpg=RA3-PA27&dq=%22qua%20tu%20tui%20pudoris%22&source=bl&ots=IfFsgUtnHv&sig=ACfU3U2m5AEkue_UBjPn_kTi7GVAslpxOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSppCdhv7wAhWFgP0HHbV8DHEQ6AEwAnoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22qua%20tu%20tui%20pudoris%22&f=false) Sebastian Sastellio:

> Deinde Saram alloquens [Abimelechus]: Fratri tuo (inquit), dedi mille argenteos, **qua** tu tui pudoris defensione apud omnes et tuos utaris et alienos.

I don't understand this *qua*, it has to be the adverbial *qua*. It seems it should mean something like: "*utaris quibus (argenteis) pro defensione ...*"

But I fail to reconstruct this from the *qua* I read in the dictionary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this sentence, *qua* is the feminine ablative singular of the relative pronoun [*qui, quae, quod*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dqui1), but you're right that this is an interesting usage!

To translate this phrase, you need to keep a few things in mind:

- *utor* ("use"), the verb in the relative clause, takes the *ablative* in Latin. (Based on your attempted recasting of the sentence, you seem to know this already!)
- Latin often pairs the relative pronoun with a new noun, particularly if the noun is "summarizing" what came before.

Here's a simpler example to illustrate this:

Caesar, *De Bello Gallico*:

> ...Dumnorix dixerat sibi a Caesare regnum civitatis deferri; **quod dictum** Haedui graviter ferebant....

Literal translation:

> ...Dumnorix had said that the rule of the city was transferred to himself; **which statement** the Haedui did not take well.

The final part would be better translated:

> ...and the Haedui did not take this statement well.

In your sentence, *qua defensione* functions exactly like *quod dictum* above, except that it is ablative to agree with *utor*.

Here's my literal translation:

> Then, speaking to Sarah, ([Abimelech] said), "I have given a thousand silver pieces to your brother, **which defense of your modesty** you may use among all your relations and strangers.

A better translation of the final part might be:

> ...which you may use as a defense of your modesty...

The construction strikes me as a *bit* artificial: I'd be interested to hear what others think.

Comment: Thanks! Castellio is fond of using *qui* as demonstrative pronoun for some reason, but I don't remember he has done so without explicitly re-mention of the subject from the previous verse as here as an apposition (which indeed it is not obvious one at least for me). Note the speaker is Abimelech (I've edited the Q to make this clear)

Comment: @d_e Yeah, I've seen that more often too. I suspect that this might grammatically parse as an apposition with the relative pronoun: L&S even mentions how the gender of the relative pronoun is sometimes "attracted" to the gender of a new noun in the relative clause. (Usually *attractio relativi* refers to changes in case, though.)

Comment: @brianpck: The concept of "attraction" came up in Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/16128/1982. In an ex. from (A & G), "urbem quam statuo vestra est" (Aen. i. 573) = "the city which I am founding is yours". The antecedent ought to be nominative, "urbs". This natural tendency ("attraction") to make everything agree appears to be legitimising a mistake--a terminology rejected by both Sebastian & Joonas. Further (A & G: p.185 sect. 306) "mare etiam quem Neptunum esse dicebas" (N. D. 3. 52) = "the sea, too, which you said was Neptune"; corresponding to neuter "mare"

Comment: @brianpck: the expected relative pronoun should be the neuter, accusative "quod". The use of "quem" attracted into accusative "Neptunum", in the relative clause. Here, in the ex. from de B. G. there is neut. acc. "regnum" (indirect speech) corresponding to relative pronoun neut. acc. "quod", which is what would be expected. Therefore how is it known that "quod" is attracted into "dictum", which could have been omitted. Presumably, it was (transfer of) "the rule" which upset the Haedui, not the announcement--shooting the messenger? Similarly, the original Q., "defensione" (feminine)

Comment: @brianpck: corresponding to fem. sing. ablative (selected by "utor") relative pronoun "qua", which is what would be expected. How are expected things to be considered as examples of "attraction"?

Comment: @tony Usually the relative pronoun agrees with the antecedent, as you mentioned, so one would normally expect *quibus* (agreeing in gender and number with *argenteos*) rather than *qua* (agreeing with the noun in the relative clause). The case is quite similar to your "mare quem Neptunum" example.